# How to find regex match between a special character and the first match of the second character?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, pandas

In one column of a pandas `df`, I have values such as `Elgin (west/ouest) (123/456), Ont, Canada` and `West/Ouest, Ont, Canada` that I want to turn into `Elgin (west) (123), Ont, Canada` and `West, Ont, Canada` by removing all characters between `/` and `)` or between `/` and `,`.

My code:

```
df_census1901['LOC2'] = df_census1901['LOC'].str.replace(r'/.*\)', ')')
df_census1901['LOC2'] = df_census1901['LOC2'].str.replace(r'/.*\,', ',')
```

The problem is it does a greedy cut into `Elgin (west), Ont, Canada`

Comment: `.*?` makes it lazy (non-greedy) which works for both of your scenarios per testing at https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a scenario like this you generally have two options:

- use a lazy quantifier `*?` (or `+?`) to avoid matching too much: `'/.*?\)'`
- use a negated range to everything to the end character: [`'/\[^)\]*)'`](https://regex101.com/r/8S0ls1/1)
  (This approach is more specific and generally faster)

Answer (score 1):

If there is alphanumeric value after the `/` until either `)` or `,` then you can match them with `\w*` such as:

```
print (df_census1901['LOC'].str.replace(r'/\w*', ''))
0    Elgin (west) (123), Ont, Canada
1                  West, Ont, Canada
Name: LOC, dtype: object
```